# Dealing with job submission limits

Tags: slurm

I am running slurm job arrays with --array, and I would like to run about 2000 tasks/array items. However this is beyond the cluster's job submission limit of ~500 at a time.

Are there any tips/best practices for splitting this up? I'd like to submit it all at once and still be able to pass the array id arguments 1-2000 to my programs if possible. I think something like waiting to submit pieces of the array might be helpful but I'm not sure how to do this at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If the limit is on the size of an array:**

You will have to split the array into several job arrays. The `--array` parameter accepts values of the form `<START>-<END>` so you can submit four jobs:

```
sbatch --array=1-500 ...
sbatch --array=501-1000 ...
sbatch --array=1001-1500 ...
sbatch --array=1501-200 ...
```

This way you will bypass the 500-limit and still keep the `SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID` ranging from 1 to 2000.

To ease things a bit, you can write this all in one line like this:

```
paste -d- <(seq 1 500 2000) <(seq 500 500 2000) | xargs -I {} sbatch --array={} ...
```

**If the limit is on the number of submitted jobs:**

Then one option is to have the last job of the array submit the following chunk.

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH ...
...
...
if [[ $((SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID % 500)) == 0 ]] ; then 
    sbatch --array=$((SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID+1))-$((SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID+500)) $0
fi
```

Note that ideally, the last running job of the array should submit the job, and it may or may not be the one with the highest TASK ID, but this has worked for all practical purposes in many situations.

Another options is to setup a [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job to monitor the queue and submit each chunk when possible, or to use a [workflow manager](https://www.commonwl.org) that will that for you.

Comment: Unfortunately the "paste" method does not work: `sbatch: error: Batch job submission failed: Job violates accounting/QOS policy (job submit limit, user's size and/or time limits)
sbatch: error: QOSMaxSubmitJobPerUserLimit`. When I run squeue only the first few hundred jobs show up, looks like this is still sending in all 2000 at once.

Comment: Ok so the limit is not on the size of a job array but on the number of job submitted by users.

Answer (score 1):

you can run a script to submit your jobs and try to make the program sleep a few seconds after every 500 submissions. see https://www.osc.edu/resources/getting_started/howto/howto_submit_multiple_jobs_using_parameters